# CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified Roo

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I'm busy doing the Pizza Tutorial and when  ever I get to the perform tests command I get the above error. I checked Windows Path and added all the necessary links to the STS file. I am at a loss. This is the fourth time I have tried this tutorial and get stuck at this command. Please help, it is frustrating me.

Answer (score 17):

In case someone stumbles upon this problem again, recent versions of maven for windows renamed the executable to `mvn.cmd` while Spring Roo expects `mvn.bat` to be there. Just copy mvn.cmd and rename the copy to mvn.bat and the `perform` commands should work.

Comment: Worked like a champ!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Check that you have Maven installed and that it's included in your PATH.
(the "perform" commands in Roo Console are actually invoking Maven)

Comment: Do you mean I have to install Maven separately? I thought I came with STS as it is in the SpringSource folder? So now I'm confused?

Comment: I have restarted STS and now when I start Spring Roo I get the following error: **Lexical error at line 5, column 19.  Encountered: "\\" (92), after : ""** I have clicked on the Java source where this error is and it has this in the code `package snippet; 

public class Snippet {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  C:\Spring\apache-maven-3.0.4
 }
}
` I am learning Java at the same time and noticed that the folder location is not a valid java code? What is going on and why did it create something like that?

Comment: OK So I tried to update the path variables but still can't get it to work. I have followed the guide on maven's site and nothing. I updated the System Variables with *M2 %M2_HOME%\bin* and *M2_HOME C:\Spring\apache-maven-3.0.4* and added *%M2%* at the end of the Path variable and I still can't type MVN -Version in command line. I did this all in System Variables as opposed to User Variables.

Comment: OK It seems to work *mvn -version* when I just add the paths directy to Path variable.

Comment: Next problem, when I type perform tests I now get a JAVA_HOME variable not set. But it is set as I run *mvn -version* and it works on the command line.

Comment: OK So I got it to work. I had to restart STS and then it worked. :(